# How to write code to make the LED’s ﬂash in the following sequence?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

How to write code like this sequence? What is the meaning of 4 decimal?
For this, we had to add a delay in the code

```
led_Pin_1 1 0 0 0 
led_Pin_2 0 1 0 0 
led_Pin_3 0 0 1 0 
led_Pin_4 0 0 0 1
```

my code, It is working. But I need to convert this code to above sequence?

```
int led_Pin_1 = 11;
int led_Pin_2 = 10;
int led_Pin_3 = 9;
int led_Pin_4 = 8;

void setup() {
  pinMode(led_Pin_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_Pin_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_Pin_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_Pin_4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_1, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_2, HIGH);
  delay(200);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_3, HIGH);
  delay(200);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_4, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_1, LOW);
  delay(300);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_2, LOW);
  delay(300);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_3, LOW);
  delay(300);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_4, LOW);
  delay(300);
}
```

Comment: your third question makes no sense .... also the comment about the delay makes no sense

Comment: please help me to write this code

Comment: No sir, I asked Is my code correct or not. If incorrect my code help me

Comment: what do you see when you run the code?

Comment: read the question that you posted .... you did not ask if your code is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int led_Pin_1 = 11;
int led_Pin_2 = 10;
int led_Pin_3 = 9;
int led_Pin_4 = 8;

int led_on = 0; // Start with first (led_Pin_1)

void setup() {
  pinMode(led_Pin_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_Pin_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_Pin_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_Pin_4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_1, (led_on == 0) ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_2, (led_on == 1) ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_3, (led_on == 2) ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_4, (led_on == 3) ? HIGH : LOW);
  delay(250);

  led_on = (led_on + 1) % 4;
}
```

led_on will start with 0 (pin 1), switching only that pin on. Some explanation:

```
(led_on == 0) ? HIGH : LOW
```

This means: if (led_on == 0), than the value will be HIGH, otherwise LOW. Resulting in only pin 1 going on, if led_on is 0, and in the next loop, only pin 2 oing on, because led_on is 1 etc.

```
led_on = (led_on + 1) % 4;
```

This increases the value of led_on, but when it reaches 4, it reverts back to 0.

I don't know about the delay times you need. I guess you want to change all LEDs at once, than wait.

You can make the 4 almost identical digitalWrite lines into a function as small improvement.

If you want to do more with the LEDs, than consider storing the leds into an array and use a for loop to iterate through them.